# How to use assert function

Tags: c++, c

What does

```
assert( scanf("%d", &t) == 1 );
```

and

```
assert( 1 <= t && t <= 10 );
```

return?

My target is to contain `t` from 1 to 10.

Comment: It's technically a macro, not a function.

Comment: the first check if the user input is 1 and the other one check if the range is between 1 and 10 included

Comment: @MimiEAM, The return value of `scanf` is the number of items successfully inputted.

Comment: In addition to other comments, be aware that `assert` is only compiled in debug mode. If you compile in release mode, this line of code will disappear.

Answer (score 7):

Do not use assert with user input. Assert is designed to catch logic errors (by calling abort if the assertion fails) by crashing your program and user input should never crash your program.

But to answer your question, if NDEBUG is defined, then assert does nothing. This might be the reason why your program is not crashing as expected.

Comment: Actually it's designed to catch logic errors by _terminating_ your program at the point of failure, instead of your program _crashing_ potentially far later after having overwritten all the bytes in your music folder

Comment: i.e. I wouldn't call what `assert` does "crashing"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - To me, "crashing" is when a program terminates with a signal that makes the program drop core. That is exactly what `assert` does. What's the difference between a SIGABRT from `assert` and a SIGABRT from `malloc` or `free` on going into panic mode? You use `assert` to detect programmer errors, not user errors. To a programmer, a core dump is a great error message. To a user, a core dump is a really lousy error message.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Windows programmers are familiar with an "Abort, Retry, Ignore" choice which doesn't necessarily crash the program.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Your interpretation is certainly technically valid. I'm just saying that in practice I think it's beneficial to make a distinction between an [unexpected] crash, which would be caused by some memory violation or somesuch, and a termination scenario that's built into the program code itself, such as an assertion failure. As for the difference? In the former case, the OS aborts the process; in the latter, the program is halting itself.

Answer (score 7):

You may assume that assert is declared as the following:

```
/*!
 * Immediately crash the program if assumption is proven invalid.
 */
void assert (bool assumption);
```

If you "know" that a variable `t` will never be outside the range [1, 10] because **you wrote the code and there's no way your code could produce any other value**, then it is appropriate to *assert* that statement.

## Assert the Obvious Things

Consider the following use of assertions:

```
int t = 9;
assert (9 == t);   // A very valid assertion, if a little pedantic.
```

The above code should seem like stating the obvious. The asserted expression *is* (obviously) true, but much more importantly **any other result would be insane**. Learning that `t != 9` would wipe away all your assumptions about how C++ works, how the computer performs math and stores values, whether we exist or whether consciousness is just an illusion formed from so many aggravated electrons…

But that's the value of assertions.

Even so computers are for all practical purposes 100% deterministic, "insane" things *do* happen. It's not rare, either. In fact, we write assertions into our code *explicitly* to detect these situations and give us a chance to figure out what happened. **Consider here a few real-world causes of insane behavior**.

## Causes of "Insane" behavior

Your assertions *should* guard against such errors as…

1. Incorrect Thread Synchronization.

   ```
   int t;

   // Thread 1
   t = 9;
   assert(t == 9);

   // Thread 2
   t = 3;
   assert(t == 3);
   ```
2. Poor memory management.

   ```
   class X {
       void sayHello () {
           assert(this != NULL);   // An object that does not exist cannot say hello.
           std::cout << "Hello?" << std::endl;
       }
   };

   // Without the assertion, this code would actually run!
   X* x = NULL;
   x->sayHello();
   ```
3. Stack (or heap) corruption.

   (See [Stack corruption in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718503/stack-corruption-in-c) for reasonable examples.)

## Behavior that is inconvenient, but not insane:

Although it may drastically alter your program's execution path, these things are *inappropriate* for assertions. Throw an exception, print an error, close the program nicely, and clean up your program's resources responsibly. **Do not assert against these "failures"!**

1. The user inputs something ridiculous.

   ```
   int t;
   scanf("%d", &t);
   assert ( 0 <= t <= 10 );       // What, are you friends with this user?
                                  // You're going to let him crash your program?
   ```
2. Some I/O device fails.

   ```
   int s = socket();
   // blah blah connect blah blah

   char buffer[64];
   int bytes_received = recv(s, buffer, 64, NULL);
   assert (bytes_received > 0);   // Do you know how hard it is to send a packet
                                  // from Estonia to the US?!
   ```

This list is incomplete, but it ought to give you a broader guide for how (and how not) to apply assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Assert returns nothing, if the parameter is false, the program is terminated.  Assert is intended for situations that should not ever be able to happen...  but you check just in case you mis-assumed or such.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/

Answer (score 1):

```
assert( expression );​
```

What assert does is evaluate *expression*, and if what it evaluates compares to 0/false, the program is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of answer I would expect:

Specifiy

```
#include <assert.h>
```

in a separate line at the beginning of your sourcefile.

Now you can use assert(bool) to terminate your program whenever bool is not true.

(The other answers are about the question: "how to use assert properly")

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution to your problem is to encapsulate the `scanf()` function in a function which knows what it's doing:

```
int AskNumberOfWidgetFrobs() {
  int count = 0;
  for(;;) // Until we get a valid number
    scanf("%d", &count);
     if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
       return count;
    } else {
       printf("%d is not a valid number of WidgetFrobs\n", count);
    }
  }
}
```