# stack around variable is corrupted when variable num is used

Tags: c++

When the variable `num` is used it I get a stack corrupted error while I'm accessing the 9th index but when I access with any other name it gives an error. Please explain me this ambiguity.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 9;

class A
{
private:

    int num[SIZE];
    int num_2[SIZE];
public:
A()
{
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 9 ; i++)
    {
        num_2[i] = i;
    }  
}
};
void main()
{
    A obj;
}
```

Comment: Side comment: your code is incorrect, it's `int main()`, not `void`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `SIZE = 9` then your loop should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
```

C++ uses 0-based indexing, so the first index of the array is `[0]` and the last is `[SIZE-1]`

Comment: but when i use num variable,... it does npt give error ??? why  but it gives error when using variable anyother variable name

Comment: @JunaidLodhi Assigning to an [array out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/c-accesses-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why) is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a). It could do anything. It could perform the assignment, throw an exception, blow up your computer... anything! You saw that the same mistake with two different arrays resulted in two different behaviors, I hope that proves my point.

Comment: if it's an exception then brother it wasted my hours.... just to check why it's not giving error for num and giving error for num_2

Comment: As I said it is undefined behavior. It is possible to get a [`SEGFAULT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault), [stack corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718503/stack-corruption-in-c), or maybe nothing! It depends on what is at that memory location already and what your computer decides to do about it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `i <= 9`
`num_2[9]` is beyond the end of `num_2`