# Search through memory in VS2017

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, postmortem-debugging

I have opened a minidump file of my C++ application in Visual Studio 2017. The dump is of a program crashing with an access violation. I am suspecting heap/stack corruption, so I am spending a lot of time in the memory/disassembly window, trying to interpret the stack.

It would be very convenient if I could search the memory for some value (for example the return address of function calls). I know WinDbg can do it, but it currently doesn't have symbol paths set up correctly, and I'd much rather stay in one debugger.

I've found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms171362(v=vs.100)) that says Visual Studio 2010 supported typing something like `.S -D 0x20B4EC L100 0x12EC9275` in the immediate window, but when I try in VS2017, I just get `expected an expression`.

Am I missing something?

(Note, Although I am now analysing a crashdump, it doesn't seem to work while debugging a live program either)

**Clarification**

- I have a minidump with memory included
- Regular analysis works fine: I have pdb files, I can see threads, stacks, watches, you name it. It is just that I suspect [stack corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718503/stack-corruption-in-c), so those do not make much sense. (Either that, or the optimizer is messing with me)
- Hence, I've opened the memory window (Click Debug->Windows->Memory->Memory 1). In there, I can see (raw) memory. Now, I want to search in that memory for specific values.

Comment: `but it currently doesn't have symbol paths set up correctly` why don't you just set it up?

Comment: I am not familiar with WinDbg at all. So after learning how to set up symbol paths, I'd have to learn how to further use it. I could, of course, but it is more of a last resort thing. If the debugger I am familiar with supports the same functionality, then that would be preferable.

Comment: What you need, I guess, is getting a stack trace of your crash. I would go with WinDbg option + *.pdb files. You might load all in WinDbg and run, for example, `!analyze -v` command. It may help you to understand the problem better.

Comment: If you have the enterprise version of VS2017, you might give `Reverse Debugging` a shot.  I believe VS calls it "IntelliTrace".

Comment: Reverse debugging is convenient if you can actually reproduce the problem. I cannot. I am investigating a crashdump created by one of our customers. This problem is hard (if not nearly impossible) to reproduce, yet occurs often enough to annoy our customers. Besides, I "only" have VS professional

Comment: Maybe you need to use [Dumpchk.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/crash-dump-analysis#using-dumpchkexe) to check if the dump file is created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019

Basically, there are some hard requirements to see the memory in your dump:

- minidump must be with heap
- you must give Visual Studio the .exe and its .pdb

If these are not met, you get only the stack trace and maybe some stack variables.

**Edit:** The stack trace with watches and variables is the same memory you want to search. There is no live debugging. It’s a snapshot of the crash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got all of those bases covered. The tutorial is too basic for what I'm trying to do. See also the clarification, above.

Comment: I updated my answer. You’re looking for live debugging. What you have is what you get with dumps.

Comment: As stated in my question, WinDbg can do it (with dumps), and so could VS2010 (alledgedly).

Additionally, in live debugging, there seems to be no searching functionality either. (I get the feeling you're not understanding me)

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted: "This option is valid only for C++ projects in runtime mode."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms171363(v=vs.100)

It does not work for crash dumps (I found this while searching for how to do something similar). Sounds like Windbg is the only way to do it.